# Why make selection sort stable?

Tags: algorithm, selection-sort, stable-sort

I am currently learning algorithms. While learning selection sort I came to know that selection sort is unstable as it swaps two elements. It can be made stable by inserting elements instead of swapping.

So if we have a array a = {2<sub>a</sub> ,2<sub>b</sub>, 1}

Unstable selection sort, sorts a={1, 2<sub>b</sub> ,2<sub>a</sub>}

and stable selection sort, sorts
s
a={1, 2<sub>a</sub> ,2<sub>b</sub>}

But actually the output is the same a={1, 2, 2}

So should I be concerned about selection sort being stable or unstable?
There might be something I am missing.

### TL;DR

In which cases I might need a stable selection sort?